# Tkinter get mouse coordinates on click and use them as variables

Tags: python, tkinter, click, coordinates, mouse

I am completely new to Python. Therefore don't get too mad at me, because I am sure that there are basic things that I am missing. Here is my problem:

I am trying to extract mouse-click coordinates from an image and use those coordinates as variables.

The code allows to import and image, from which I want to extract the coordinates. Some prompts ask the user about size and extent of the diagram, after which I would like to set up a coordinate grid by clicking the origin, and the end point on the x- and y-axes respectively. The idea is to use these 3 sets of coordinates and transform them into Pressure and Temperature coordinates through some transformation functions (see code).

```
# Determine the origin by clicking
# Probably with classes??
class Origin:
    def getorigin(eventorigin):
          eventorigin.x0 = eventorigin.x
          eventorigin.y0 = eventorigin.y
    #mouseclick event
    w.bind("<Button 1>",getorigin)
# What do I do here??
x0 = ...
y0 = ...
```

I don't really know how to assign the coordinates that I get through clicking, to a new variable that I can use later in the code.

I can print the coordinates, but since they are a function, they are local and are not usable outside of the function (as far as I could understand). So, and approach using classes might be better, but I have no idea how to do that.

Any help is appreciated.

FULL CODE (ADAPTED):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter.simpledialog

root = Tk()

#setting up a tkinter canvas
w = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=1000)
w.pack()

#adding the image
File = askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir="./",title='Select an image')
original = Image.open(File)
original = original.resize((1000,1000)) #resize image
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(original)
w.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor="nw")

#ask for pressure and temperature extent
xmt = tkinter.simpledialog.askfloat("Temperature", "degrees in x-axis")
ymp = tkinter.simpledialog.askfloat("Pressure", "bars in y-axis")

#ask for real PT values at origin
xc = tkinter.simpledialog.askfloat("Temperature", "Temperature at origin")
yc = tkinter.simpledialog.askfloat("Pressure", "Pressure at origin")

#instruction on 3 point selection to define grid
tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Instructions", "Click: \n" 
                                            "1) Origin \n"
                                            "2) Temperature end \n"
                                            "3) Pressure end")

# From here on I have no idea how to get it to work...

# Determine the origin by clicking
def getorigin(eventorigin):
    global x0,y0
    x0 = eventorigin.x
    y0 = eventorigin.y
    print(x0,y0)
#mouseclick event
w.bind("<Button 1>",getorigin)

# Determine the extent of the figure in the x direction (Temperature)
def getextentx(eventextentx):
    global xe
    xe = eventextentx.x
    print(xe)
#mouseclick event
w.bind("<Button 1>",getextentx)

# Determine the extent of the figure in the y direction (Pressure)
def getextenty(eventextenty):
    global ye
    ye = eventextenty.y
    print(ye)
#mouseclick event
w.bind("<Button 1>",getextenty)

#message to confirm that the grid is set up
tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Grid", "Grid is set. You can start picking coordinates.")

#Coordinate transformation into Pressure-Temperature space
def printcoords(event):
    xmpx = xe-x0
    xm = xmt/xmpx
    ympx = ye-y0
    ym = -ymp/ympx

    #coordinate transformation
    newx = (event.x-x0)*(xm)+xc
    newy = (event.y-y0)*(ym)+yc

    #outputting x and y coords to console
    print (newx,newy)
#mouseclick event
w.bind("<Button 1>",printcoords)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If what I said in my previous comment is what you're trying to do, since tkinter doesn't pause the program to wait for a mouse click event you will have to do this: it rebinds it every time the mouse button  get clicked

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter.simpledialog

root = Tk()

#setting up a tkinter canvas
w = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=1000)
w.pack()

#adding the image
File = askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir="./",title='Select an image')
original = Image.open(File)
original = original.resize((1000,1000)) #resize image
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(original)
w.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor="nw")

#ask for pressure and temperature extent
xmt = tkinter.simpledialog.askfloat("Temperature", "degrees in x-axis")
ymp = tkinter.simpledialog.askfloat("Pressure", "bars in y-axis")

#ask for real PT values at origin
xc = tkinter.simpledialog.askfloat("Temperature", "Temperature at origin")
yc = tkinter.simpledialog.askfloat("Pressure", "Pressure at origin")

#instruction on 3 point selection to define grid
tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Instructions", "Click: \n" 
                                            "1) Origin \n"
                                            "2) Temperature end \n"
                                            "3) Pressure end")

# From here on I have no idea how to get it to work...

# Determine the origin by clicking
def getorigin(eventorigin):
    global x0,y0
    x0 = eventorigin.x
    y0 = eventorigin.y
    print(x0,y0)
    w.bind("<Button 1>",getextentx)
#mouseclick event
w.bind("<Button 1>",getorigin)

# Determine the extent of the figure in the x direction (Temperature)
def getextentx(eventextentx):
    global xe
    xe = eventextentx.x
    print(xe)
    w.bind("<Button 1>",getextenty)

# Determine the extent of the figure in the y direction (Pressure)
def getextenty(eventextenty):
    global ye
    ye = eventextenty.y
    print(ye)
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Grid", "Grid is set. You can start picking coordinates.")
    w.bind("<Button 1>",printcoords)

#Coordinate transformation into Pressure-Temperature space
def printcoords(event):
    xmpx = xe-x0
    xm = xmt/xmpx
    ympx = ye-y0
    ym = -ymp/ympx

    #coordinate transformation
    newx = (event.x-x0)*(xm)+xc
    newy = (event.y-y0)*(ym)+yc

    #outputting x and y coords to console
    print (newx,newy)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: WOW, that seems to do what I want (I might have to adapt my transformations, but the program is otherwise fine!) I am doing some other stuff right now, but will test and comment later. Thanks!

Comment: Everything works. Thanks! (only had to change `ympx=ye-y0` to `ympx=y0-ye` to flip the coordinate system (but that has nothing to do with the question, ahaha).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to set x, y to global, class or not doesn't matter.
I didn't see your full code because I can't open zip files on my phone. So here's what I can help with your example

```
import tkinter as tk
def getorigin(eventorigin):
      global x,y
      x = eventorigin.x
      y = eventorigin.y
      print(x,y)

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind("<Button 1>",getorigin)
```

Comment: I adapted the code. The piece itself seem to work, but in the context of the full code it doesn't. If I try  `print(x,y)` at the end, the error message `NameError: name 'x' is not defined` is showed. Could it be that I need some kind of an `if` statement or loop in order to be able to save the 3 coordinates one after the other?

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzPi9vLwoHnZUTVPZnlLaXVGRWs) is the adapted version of the full code

Comment: @Lele do you mind copy and paste your adapted code to your question under EDIT. I am on my phone so I can't view .py files

Comment: @Lele you can only bind "<Button 1>" once using w.bind. Doing so repeatedly just replace the previous bind

Comment: Are you're trying to make the program to wait for the user to press something? Then continue to wait for the user to press something else again?

Comment: that is exactly what I want to do. `you can only bind "<Button 1>" once using w.bind` : I guess I learned something new today :-) Thanks!